# DownloadStringTaskAsync on WP7 hangs when retrieving Result

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-ctp

I converted a bunch of WP7 code to use DownloadStringTaskAsync instead of DownloadStringAsync using the Async CTP SP1.  It wasn't working so I boiled down my code a bunch and ended up with these 2 lines:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var result = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.weather.gov").Result;
```

If I run this method with a console app on my windows machine.  Its works as I expect and I get a string with the contents of weather.gov.  If I run the same 2 lines in the constructor of App in a blank WP7 app, it hangs while waiting for Result to become available.

Can anyone help me fix these lines so they will work on the phone?  Or is this a bug in the CTP and I should skip it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone brings back HTTP requests on the UI thread. By accessing `Result`, you are blocking the UI thread, thus making it impossible for the response to come back.

Considering you are using the async CTP, why would you want to block at all?

```
var result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.weather.gov");
```

Comment: Richard is exactly right here - you are using an asynchronous API, so you should not be blocking on its result.

The right way to consume this with the Async CTP is to add the async modifier on that method, and anything up its call chain. Then the chained method calls instead of being direct calls are more like "await LowerMethodCall(...)".

Last thing to be wary of, just like the Result property, Wait() should not be called on Tasks while on the UI thread, unless you are certain that those tasks don't need the UI thread to process in order to complete.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.  My actual code uses await/async, I found this problem while trying to figure out what was going on and thought I would ask.