# Windows Phone 7.1: AutoResetEvent does not work with Service Methods?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, autoresetevent

After adding Service Reference to my Phone Application (for example http://www.deeptraining.com/webservices/weather.asmx?op=GetWeather), I tried to use AutoResetEvent for emulation syncronous method calling. But after calling WaitOne, method Set is never called. Why? Is it a bug?

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private string _result;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var weatherSoapClient = new WeatherSoapClient();

        weatherSoapClient.GetWeatherCompleted += weatherSoapClient_GetWeatherCompleted;
        weatherSoapClient.GetWeatherAsync("Pekin");

        _autoResetEvent.WaitOne(); // Program stop hire

        textBlock1.Text = _result;
    }

    void weatherSoapClient_GetWeatherCompleted(object sender, GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _result = e.Result;
        _autoResetEvent.Set(); // Never invoke! Why???
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DownloadStringTaskAsync on WP7 hangs when retrieving Result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448819/downloadstringtaskasync-on-wp7-hangs-when-retrieving-result)

Answer (score 0):

In WP7, HTTP responses are processed on the UI thread. Bocking the UI thread prevents the response from being processed.